# Keep access to variables between pipe operators

Tags: node.js, rxjs6

I have been trying to use Rxjs in a node app. `fileList$` is the return from `fs.readdirsync` (an array of strings).

The first `map()` has a parameter called filename.

`flatMap() readFileAsObservable()` uses `bindNodeCallback(fs.readFile)` to read the file.

My class `Testian` takes 2 args; The object created by `yaml-js` from reading the file and the `filename` from the first map. How can I access `filename` in the pipe where I have indicated?

```
fileList$
    .pipe(
        map((filename: string) => `${resolvedDirPath}/${filename}`),
        flatMap(
            (filePath: string) => readFileAsObservable(filePath, 'utf8') as Observable<string>
        ),
        map((fileData: string) => yaml.safeLoad(fileData) as ITestYaml),
        map((testYaml: ITestYaml) => new Testian(testYaml, [I want to use filename here])),
        flatMap((testYaml: Testian) => {
            const prom: Promise<{}> = activeTests.set(testYaml);
            outgoing.sendTest(testYaml);
            return from(prom);
        })
    )
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is treated similarly in any API that involve chained functions, e.g. promises.

## Temporary variable

A temporary variable can be used to store a value that is out of the scope of a function that should access it. This is an easy but non-idiomatic workaround:

```
let filename;

fileList$.pipe(
    map((_filename) => {
      filename = _filename;
      return `${resolvedDirPath}/${filename}`;
    }),
    flatMap((filePath) => readFileAsObservable(filePath, 'utf8')),
    map((fileData) => yaml.safeLoad(fileData)),
    map((testYaml) => new Testian(testYaml, filename)),
    flatMap((testYaml) => {
        const prom = activeTests.set(testYaml);
        outgoing.sendTest(testYaml);
        return from(prom);
    })
)
```

There may be problems with race conditions, depending on particular observable.

## Nested function

A function that uses `filename` can be nested to access the variable from parent scope:

```
fileList$.pipe(
    flatMap((filename) => of(`${resolvedDirPath}/${filename}`).pipe(
        flatMap((filePath) => readFileAsObservable(filePath, 'utf8')),
        map((fileData) => yaml.safeLoad(fileData)),
        map((testYaml) => new Testian(testYaml, filename)
    ),
    flatMap((testYaml) => {
        const prom = activeTests.set(testYaml);
        outgoing.sendTest(testYaml);
        return from(prom);
    })
)
```

## Pass-through value

The variable can be passed altogether with other other results where possible:

```
fileList$.pipe(
    map((filename) => [filename, `${resolvedDirPath}/${filename}`]),
    flatMap(
        ([filename, filePath]) => forkJoin(filename, readFileAsObservable(filePath, 'utf8')),
    ),
    map(([filename, fileData]) => [filename, yaml.safeLoad(fileData) as ITestYaml)],
    map(([filename, testYaml]) => new Testian(testYaml, filename)),
    flatMap((testYaml) => {
        const prom = activeTests.set(testYaml);
        outgoing.sendTest(testYaml);
        return from(prom);
    })
)
```

## async..await

If a stream allows to switch to promises and `async..await`, this can be done because the problem with function scopes doesn't exist in `async` function.

```
fileList$.pipe(
    flatMap(async (filename) => {
      const filePath = `${resolvedDirPath}/${filename}`;
      const fileData = await readFileAsObservable(filePath, 'utf8').toPromise();
      let testYaml = yaml.safeLoad(fileData);
      testYaml = new Testian(testYaml, filename);
      const prom = activeTests.set(testYaml);
      outgoing.sendTest(testYaml);
      return prom;
    })
)
```

Since this observable already uses `flatMap` and promises, it could be safely written with promises alone. RxJS observables have use cases that aren't suitable for promises, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: I much prefer your async..await solution! I was actually just practising RxJs in this case. Thanks you for your insight.

Comment: You're welcome. At this point fileList$ is pretty much useless; it could be iterated with for..of in async function. Observables are great but less useful on server side; promises and Node streams usually cover most cases.